# Read LaTeX preamble

Tags: php, web-services, latex, api, web-apis

Can someone suggest me a library/tool/webservice/api used to read and process the preamble of a LaTeX file? I would prefer it in PHP, but any back-end language will suffice. I just need to check if a document it's formatted according to a set standard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a simple string comparison be enough? Some samples would be helpful to make your question answerable.

Comment: What standard should documents meet? Something like a style guide or rather something like "does it compile"?

Comment: Something like a style guide